# How to calculate F4 age limit

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, greencard

My uncle filed for the F4 visa in 2004. The priority date is October 4th, 2004.

At the time of the filing and priority date I was 9 years old (born on the 23rd of September 1994).

I don't know the approval date of the form I130, but the year is on 2010

I just want to know if CSPA applies to me and will I be able to attain, or am eligible for, a visa since I am now 25. 
 my date of birth is 23 september 1994. Our interview is on november 20th 2019

Could you please help me to find the answer to this problem, since our 4 children that have a similar situation. Their dob are given respectivly 03/01/1996,10/09/1995,17/09/1991 and mine 23/09/1994 (dates given in English format dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times. Use the "Search on Expatriates" text entry box at the top, and search for "Aged Out." Read the first three or four entries, and you'll know much more.

Comment: I need to know mine, not about others.i know there is similar questions, but that was based on their age criteria, i would like to hear from user102008. Could u please help me to know if u had seen my question. I edited it.

Comment: Anyone help me to answer

Comment: What country were you and your siblings born in?

Comment: India, F4 category

Answer (score 1):

The I-130 petition was pending for approximately 6 years (we don't have the exact date of approval; it might be anywhere between 5 years 3 months to 6 years 3 months). So you will not age out until you are age 21 + (the length of time the I-130 was pending), which is somewhere between 26 years 3 months to 27 years 3 months.

Assuming you guys were all born in India, the priority date became current in November 1, 2019. Assuming it doesn't retrogress, you look at your ages at the time it became current; you are 25 and your siblings are 23, 24, and 28. The oldest sibling has aged out, but you and the two younger siblings have not aged out, and qualify as derivative beneficiaries, as long as it doesn't retrogress, and you seek to acquire a visa within one year of it becoming available.

Comment: Thank you so much @user102008

Answer (score 0):

My Visa is approved. Age is calculated as per above norms.

Comment: Congrats on the visa approval. Would you please edit this into your question? Answers aren't meant for updates.